# Use git pre-commit hook to inspect the eventual state of the repo?

Tags: git, pre-commit-hook

Say I have a git repo with a `pre-commit` hook and I've edited a bunch of file but I'm only committing some of them. Or I (by mistake) have further edits that happened after I last added some files to the commit. However it happens, I have edits in the files that are not in the index and thus they can be seen by the hook but will not be part of the commit. If someone else were to check out that commit, the hook would fail for them.

Is there an easy way to get a directory that matches what would be the post commit state (i.e. what I'd get if a were to do a fresh clone from the commit I'm expecting to create) so that the hook can test *that*, rather than the working directory?

---

I *think* I could hack something together via something like:

```
OLDR=$PWD
NEWR=$(mktemp -d -t hook-XXXXXXXXXX)
HEAD=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
INDEX=$(mktemp -t hook-XXXXXXXXXX.patch)
git diff --staged > $INDEX

cd $NEWR
git clone $OLDR $NEWR
git checkout $HEAD
git apply $INDEX

...
```

but that seems ... more than a bit of a hack, and I'm not sure how reliably I can trust it to work across versions and OS's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is extract the content's of Git's index, as defined by the `$GIT_INDEX_FILE` variable if it's set, or the default index if not.

The sequence:

```
dir=$(mktemp -d)
git checkout-index --prefix=${dir}/ -a
```

will do the trick, populating the new temporary directory.  (This fragment doesn't clean up after itself, of course, and your omits your `-t` template; it's just meant as a minimal demo.)

Unfortunately, this simple method is typically insufficient, since you typically might also want any *untracked* files.  Making this all work really well is quite difficult.

There's a rather fancy program called `pre-commit` described [here](https://pre-commit.com/) that tries to handle everything.  I have not actually used it.

Comment: Actually, I'd consider excluding un-tracked files as a feature not a bug as as they won't be present in the resulting commit. ... unless you are saying that won't include already committed files?

Comment: Regardless of what you intended, that seems to work.

Comment: What I mean is: a lot of people want the build to include the untracked "next version number" file, or whatever, that's sitting around in the working tree. Since this method makes an empty directory and then extracts just the to-be-committed files, they don't get those files. If that's what you *want*, great! If not, well, that's when it becomes insufficient.